# Populate a table in rails 5 using an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a migration in my rails 5 app and I am trying to populate a column with a list of items.

Basically I have a table that breaks down loans by sector.. I am trying to populate the table through the migration file  but its not populating it.

Heres is my migration file:

```
class CreateLoanSectors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :loan_sectors do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps

    loan_sector = ['Agriculture/Farming',         'Bars/Public Houses',     'B&B’s'    ,     'Beauty',      'Bio Pharma Engineering',
                    'Cafes',    'Car Sales Industry',     'Construction - Commercial' ,     'Construction - Residential',
                    'Consultancy',   'Distribution Services',    'Education',      'Engineering',       'Entertainment',
                    'Environmental and CleanTech Products and Services',     'Financial Services' ,   'Garages—Car Repair etc.',
                    'Health',      'Hotels',    'Legal services',    'Marketing Services',    'Media Services',    'Motor Industry',
                    'Manufacturing' ,     'Pharmaceuticals',      'Recruitment Services' ,      'Restaurants',        'Retail Services',
                    'Telecoms Industry',   'Tourism',   'Transport - Import',         'Transport - Export',
                    'Transport - Internal',    'Wholesale'].each do |name|

      LoanSector.create(name: name)


      end
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :loan_sectors
  end
end
```

Error:

```
== 20180802115704 CreateLoanSectors: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:loan_sectors)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'flender_development.loan_sectors' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `loan_sectors`
```

Comment: Include your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for LoanSector` most likely. This is because you just added `name` attribute to your model, but it has not been reloaded and the `ActiveModel` does not know of its existence. Do [LoanSector.reset_column_information](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class) right after you `create_table`.

Couple more things:

1. Move you loop inside `change` method
2. And you don't really need `down` method in this case. `ActiveRecord::Migration` is smart enough to know how to `down`.

Comment: Hi I have edited the source. I ran rake db:rollback then changed the source to what it is now. And now I am getting a MySQL error (see error above)

Comment: I see the problem I had. The create table function was not ended in the correct place. Thank you